# Why should I have 2x versions of icons of the same sizes for deploying my applications to Mac OS

Tags: c++, macos, qt, deployment, qt5

It is not clear for me why should I have `@2x` versions of icons of the same sizes for deploying my applications to Mac OS (for example, written via Qt).

I [saw](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/59561/where-did-icon-composer-go-from-xcode) that I must have the following set of `png`s:

```
icon_16x16.png
icon_16x16@2x.png
icon_32x32.png
icon_32x32@2x.png
icon_128x128.png
icon_128x128@2x.png
icon_256x256.png
icon_256x256@2x.png
icon_512x512.png
icon_512x512@2x.png
```

What is the difference between, for example, `icon_256x256@2x.png` and `icon_512x512.png` (the same goes for all other sizes)?

When the `@2x` version will be used instead of its equivalent? Are they the same at all?

It is not clear for me enough both in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/HighResolutionOSX/Optimizing/Optimizing.html)

> The inclusion of the @2x modifier for the
>   high-resolution image lets the system know that the image is the
>   high-resolution variant of the standard image

and the comments [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/59561/where-did-icon-composer-go-from-xcode):

> the difference is UID. While a 128x128@2x may be technically able to
>   display the same data as an 256x256@1x, the output would be a lot
>   smaller on the 128 variant and as such a human looking at it may
>   benefit from simplified graphics at 2x resolutions

Answer (score 2):

Due to the Retina screens on some Macs (Retina MBP, Retina iMac etc) it requires icons that can be scaled according to the users resolution choice. Proving the `@2X` just allows the OS to pick an icon size that'll be presented nicely.

Comment: So, can I just make a copy of any file (for example, `icon_512x512.png`) and rename it to the smaller equivalent (for example, `icon_256x256@2x.png`)?

Comment: What you're meant to do is export them at the multiplied value, so `128x128@2X` would be an icon size in pixels of 256x256, `256x256@2X` becomes 512x512 and so on. I personally just use an icon generator to do it for me (but I can't remember the name, sorry!).

Comment: Maybe it's `iconutil`? Or is it web-based?

Comment: It was definitely a download, but I'm not on my main machine atm and I can't seem to find it on Google. It probably was just a wrapper around `iconutil` though.

Comment: "it requires icons that can be scaled according to the users resolution choice" -- it sounds too abstract for me anyway. Why OS can even think about displaying icons in these "stretched" format instead of the fully-sized non-stretched icons? And even then, why can't OS just do it by itself?

Comment: I'm sure they could potentially do doubling, but then there's risks with icon quality so they leave it on the developer to manage it. With the Retina screen it's going to always require double the amount of pixels for the icon size, and if the user has selected a scale option then it can degrade gracefully.